# Using sqlldr to load csv file with sequence

Tags: oracle, sql-loader

Is it possible to load csv file with sqlldr and use sequence at the same time?

Say for example I would like to use command

```
sqlldr id/pass@'ip:1521/ORCL' data=path\csv_test.csv  
control=path\control.ctl log=path\log.log bad=path\bad.csv
```

to load `csv` file into database but at the same time use sequence to create an extra column that increments for every `csv` file insert (so every bulk insert of a csv file)

Comment: Which release of Oracle are you using? For versions 12.1 and later, you could make use of identity columns or DEFAULT Values Using Sequences : https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/default-values-for-table-columns-enhancements-12cr1

Comment: @KaushikNayak unfortunately version 11. Is it not possible with v11?

Answer (score 2):

Sure there's an option; it is called a *sequence*. More info about it in [Field List Reference](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28319/ldr_field_list.htm#g1044967) documentation.

Here's an example.

Data will be loaded into the TEST table:

```
SQL> create table test
  2  (id    number,
  3   ename varchar2(20)
  4  );

Table created.

SQL>
```

A *sequence* will be used for the ID column. Control file looks like this:

```
load data
infile *
replace
into table test
(
id     sequence,
ename  char terminated by whitespace
)
begindata
Little
Foot
Stack
Over
Flow
```

Loading session:

```
M:\a1_maknuto>sqlldr scott/tiger@orcl control=test21.ctl

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pon Vel 19 07:20:29 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 4
Commit point reached - logical record count 5
```

Results:

```
SQL> select * From test;

        ID ENAME
---------- --------------------
         1 Little
         2 Foot
         3 Stack
         4 Over
         5 Flow

SQL>
```

**[EDIT: aha, all rows should share the same "sequence"]**

OK then, try something like this (note expression used for the ID column):

```
load data
infile *
append
into table test
(
id     expression "userenv('sessionid')",
ename  char(30) terminated by whitespace  
)
begindata
Little
Foot
Stack
Over
Flow
```

A few loading sessions:

```
SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@orcl control=test21.ctl

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pon Vel 19 08:13:23 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 4
Commit point reached - logical record count 5

SQL> select * From test;

        ID ENAME
---------- --------------------
   4530297 Little
   4530297 Foot
   4530297 Stack
   4530297 Over
   4530297 Flow

SQL> $sqlldr scott/tiger@orcl control=test21.ctl

SQL*Loader: Release 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on Pon Vel 19 08:13:30 2018

Copyright (c) 1982, 2009, Oracle and/or its affiliates.  All rights reserved.

Commit point reached - logical record count 4
Commit point reached - logical record count 5

SQL> select * From test;

        ID ENAME
---------- --------------------
   4530297 Little
   4530297 Foot
   4530297 Stack
   4530297 Over
   4530297 Flow
   4530301 Little
   4530301 Foot
   4530301 Stack
   4530301 Over
   4530301 Flow

10 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Alternatively, you could use a *sequence* (an Oracle object). That's a little bit more "complex" (you'd need a function too) but - if you need it, I can create an example. Say so.

Comment: Ah! I think I used it 6 years ago and forgotten this thing completely. +1

Comment: Hi, thanks but I need the sequence to increment for each csv. So all the rows in first CSV insert will have 1 as ID but second CSV will have 2 for all the rows. Is this possible? And I need to use sequence because of the thread safety so that I can distinguish each bulk inserts in the same table

Comment: I created a new example & edited my answer; have a look, please.